# Xamarin forms, RecyclerView, cell rendering from xaml

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, cellrenderer

I want to create control in Xamarin.Forms that uses native android RecyclerView as renderer.

My problem occurs when i try create cell that contains labels or other controls with HorizontalOptions different than: Default, Fill and FillAndExpand. That labels just don't render themselves ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKXcG.png)). thisis my .xaml cell code

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<self:FormsRecyclerCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:self="clr-namespace:FormsRecyclerViewApp;assembly:FormsRecyclerViewApp" x:Class="FormsRecyclerViewApp.FormsRecyclerCellTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="Blue" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="Horizontal Start"  BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Horizontal StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" />
    <Label Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Text="Horizontal Fill" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />
    <Label Grid.Row="4" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Horizontal FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />
    <Label Grid.Row="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Horizontal Center" BackgroundColor="Bisque" />
    <Label Grid.Row="6" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Horizontal CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Bisque" />
    <Label Grid.Row="7" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="Horizontal End" BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond" />
    <Label Grid.Row="8" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="Horizontal EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond" />
    <Label Grid.Row="9" Text="Horizontal Default" BackgroundColor="Azure"/>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="10" BackgroundColor="Green" />
  </Grid>
</self:FormsRecyclerCell>
```

For rendering things inside RecyclerView i'm using CellContainer that creates PlatformRenderer and overrides methods OnLayout and OnMeasure

FormsRecyclerViewCellContainer.cs

```
 protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        using (var handler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper))
        {
            handler.Post(() =>
            {
                double width = Context.FromPixels(r - l);
                double height = Context.FromPixels(b - t);

                Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(this.view.Element, new XForms.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
                this.view.UpdateLayout();
            });
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        if (this.view == null || this.view.Element == null)
        {
            base.SetMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }

        XForms.SizeRequest measure = this.view.Element.Measure(this.initialWidth, double.PositiveInfinity, XForms.MeasureFlags.IncludeMargins);
        int height = (int)Context.ToPixels(this.fastCell.Height > 0 ? this.fastCell.Height : measure.Request.Height);
        this.SetMeasuredDimension((int)Context.ToPixels(this.initialWidth), height);
    }
```

**My questions:**
 - What is the best way to get native objects from forms .xaml?
 - Why some labels don't render themselves?
 - What should i do to render all VisualElemts properly?

Feel free to download my [sample project](https://github.com/PawKanarekInsys/FormsRecyclerViewApp).

Answer (score 1):

I found answer. My problem was indeed connected with HorizontalOptions, your note was useful.

> (...) Additionally it specifies if the element should consume leftover space in the X axis from the **parent** layout. (...)

I just added parent to XF version of my viewHolder. Here you can see what i changed:

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        FormsRecyclerCell fastCell;

        fastCell = this.Element.ItemTemplate.CreateContent() as FormsRecyclerCell;

        var view = new FormsRecyclerViewCellContainer(parent.Context, fastCell, parent, this.Element.ItemWidth, this.Element);
        if (this.SelectionEnabled)
        {
            view.Click += MainView_Click;
        }

        //--------------**-----------------
        //Here i added XF parent to XF cell
        fastCell.Parent = this.Element;

        var dpW = this.ConvertDpToPixels(this.Element.ItemWidth);
        var dpH = this.ConvertDpToPixels(this.Element.ItemHeight);
        view.SetMinimumWidth(dpW);
        view.SetMinimumHeight(dpH);
        view.LayoutParameters = new GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(dpW, GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        return new FormsRecyclerViewCell(view);
    }
```

It's just 1 line of code, now the labels are working perfectly with every setting of HorizontalOptions. This was very hard to find out, because native *(android)* ViewHolder had native parent, so i thought XF VievHolder instantly get the same parent but as XF version *(from renderer)*. I was mistaken, and i had to set it on my own.

I know now, that all calculations from .xaml are implemented in core of Xamarin.Forms and to proper calculations children must have their parents.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think this is a bug using `HorizontalOptions` of `Label` inside a `Grid`. Not sure, you can try to file this issue in Bugzilla.

By default [HorizontalOptions](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.View.HorizontalOptions/) is set to `LayoutOptions.Fill`, it works when this property is set by default or to `FillAndExpand`, the others with different `HorizontalOptions` has a 0 width by my side, that's why only some of your labels are shown.

A workaround to solve this issue is to give a `WidthRequest` to these labels with 0 width, but please notice that

> Assigning the HorizontalOptions modifies how the element is laid out when there is excess space available along the X axis from the parent layout. Additionally it specifies if the element should consume leftover space in the X axis from the parent layout. If multiple children of a layout are set to expand, the extra space is distributed proportionally.

Your width here should be smaller here than the parent to see the results of different `LayoutOptions`.